# Add object to an NSArray from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uitableview

I have created a customed `UITableViewCell` that contains a `PFObject` property and a button. I want the button to add this object on a `NSMutableArray` and pass this Array to another `UIViewController`. The problem is that I can't implement the `prepareForSegue` method into custom `UITableViewCell` so when I display the array in `restoCardConfirmationVC` I always get an empty array.

This is my code :

```
#import "boxTableViewCell.h"
#import "RestoCardConfirmationViewController.h"
#import "RestauCardViewController.h"

@implementation boxTableViewCell {
   NSMutableArray *_pickerPlace;
   RestauCardViewController *_restoCardVC;
   RestoCardConfirmationViewController *_restoCardConfirmationVC;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
   // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return _pickerPlace.count;
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_pickerPlace objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (IBAction)select:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"the select box is : %@",_box);
   [_restoCardConfirmationVC.boxesCommande addObject:_box];
   self.select.enabled = NO;
}
@end
```

#### RestaCardConfirmation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface RestoCardConfirmationViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic) PFObject *commande;
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boxesCommande;

- (IBAction)confirmer:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: What is that "Another view controller"? Do you allocate and present it when a row is selected in TableViewController?

Comment: @JamalZafar I have created a customed ViewTableCell with a button and I want to add a PFObject to an array

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise the array before using it. Like this

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   // Initialization code
   _restoCardConfirmationVC = [[RestoCardConfirmationViewController alloc] init];
   _restoCardConfirmationVC.boxesCommande = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Although this is a bad approach. You should initialise the array in the RestoCardConfirmationViewController initialisation.

Comment: I initialise them but I alway get empty array in restoCardConfirmationVC when I try to display the boxesCommande array

Comment: I have created a NSMutableArray property in restoCardConfirmation VC : @property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boxesCommande;

Comment: You might be pushing/presenting the wrong view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the Array in which you are adding object. Allocate it either in `awakeFromNib` or in `ViewDidLoad` and then add an object in it.

Moreover, I don't find a good reason to alloc view controller in awakeFromNib of TableViewCell. You should allocate the VC only when Button is Tapped.

Hence the code should be like:

```
- (IBAction)select:(id)sender {

    _restoCardConfirmationVC = [[RestoCardConfirmationViewController alloc] init];

    [_restoCardConfirmationVC view]; //This will call the ViewDidLoad in Advance

    [_restoCardConfirmationVC.boxesCommande addObject:_box];

   self.select.enabled = NO;
}
```

And in ViewDidLoad of RestoCardConfirmationViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _boxesCommande =  [NSMutableArray array];

    //Other initialisation code
}
```

Comment: I do it but I always get an empty array when in restoCardConfirmation View Controller

Comment: @aissaelouafi : Where are you allocating the RestoCardConfirmationViewController? update your code

Comment: I have allocated the RestoCardConfirmationViewController in the awakFromNib method : -(void)awakeFromNib {
    _restoCardConfirmationVC = [[RestoCardConfirmationViewController alloc] init];
    _restoCardConfirmationVC.boxesCommande = [NSMutableArray array];
}

Comment: Call [_restoCardConfirmationVC view] after allocating and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: I tried but I allways get the same problem. I shouldn't instanciate the boxesCommande array in the restoCardConfirmation VC too ?

Comment: if you are instantiating it from awakeFromNib, then you don't need to Re-instantiate in restoCardConfirmationVC.

Comment: Sure, I think I have a problem with the NSMutableArray property.  @property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boxesCommande;

Comment: Make it @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *boxesCommande;

Comment: Moreover move the code of array initialization to ViewDidLoad of RestoCardConfirmationViewController rather initialising in awakeFromNib

Comment: I always get the same problem :( It has been 3 days since I try to solve this problem

Comment: When I try to display the NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad I get an empty array

Comment: I always get an emplty array :(

Comment: When I add this line : NSLog(@"The array  %@",_restoCardConfirmationVC.boxesCommande);
I get the content of the array not an empty array